# How to play videos from youtube to exoplayer

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer

Please who can help me in that question, I cant play youtube videos on exoplayer "Android studio"!
Please anyone help me in that.

I would appreciate any help, but please give you answer in more details.

Thank you

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#0).